# como se escribe la @ en un campo email en el atributo pattern para que no dé error en mvc

Tags: c#, html5, mvc

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{1,5}"
```

donde la "@" sale en amarillo y la convierte en error

Comment: Saludos Lex, coloca todo el código, especificando si es Razor, JavaScript, Controlador o Modelo. Bienvenido/a a SOes :D

Comment: Solución
<label>
            Correo: <input type="email" name="correo" id="correo" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*&#64;[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{1,5}"
                           title="correo electrónico válido, con la arroba y terminación. p.e. John@algo.com" required="" placeholder="John@algo.com">
 </label>
cambiando la @ por &#64; en una vista utilizando MVC

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza doble @ para que Razor renderize de manera literal:

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*@@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{1,5}"
```